# How to get app reviewed without getting a #32 error because of their page-rate-limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am completely lost at what to do...

My Facebook app keeps getting denied because of the page-level Rate Limiting. I created a function that watches the data you get back from the header in the x-page-usage. Every time the page gets to 90% it takes them to a page where it says "Looks like you have been using facebook a lot, why don't you take a break." After a certain amount of time, it let's them back in.

When I test it with my own pages, I only use around 20 calls per page, and that is in the whole functionality of my app.
I created a test user for them to use and I even created a test page in the test account that they could use my app with. They didn't use it and of course, they reached their page rate limit and they were taken to my page that asks them to take a break.

How do you get around this? How can I respect Facebook's wishes and throttle a user and get my app approved? I have attached the screens shots below so you can better understand my problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is the link of the page they get taken to when they are about to hit or they have hit their limit. This is also the page that they screenshot and sent back to me.

https://stage.zampi.io/index.php/account/overlimit

here is their pages limit 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPOw8.jpg

here is our apps with theirs
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0peeN.jpg

Comment: that´s a LOT of api calls, what are you doing exactly? that´s the most important question at the moment, i guess.

Comment: Do you mean that 20 is a lot of api calls?

I am letting the user connect their fb page with our account. I am making 1 call to get a list of all of their pages associated with their personal account. I then make a call to get the img of each account. After that, the user can post content on their page from our app. That only uses one additional api call.

Comment: but what about those 15.054 calls in the screenshot for "cookie crumble"? i guess i don´t have the full picture of the problem yet...

Comment: So a page-limit isn't based just on my app. It is based on every app that page interacts with. So the page cookie crumble is a facebook tester page. They are using that page to test a whole bunch of apps. One of those other apps can be increasing it to the 1.5k

That is why I included my pages as a reference. My app only makes 20 calls. Depending on how you use it. But because they are already over their limit, the app won't function, facebook blocks it. So how do I play by their rules and still get my app approved? It seems like I am missing something...